# Cincom Visualworks Smalltalk - Class Methods Initialization

Tags: smalltalk

Apologies for the newbie question, but I failed to figure this despite of long try.

I created a matrix class using NewClass feature in Cincom Visualworks.

```
Smalltalk.Core defineClass: #Matrix
    superclass: #{Core.Object}
    indexedType: #none
    private: false
    instanceVariableNames: 'rowCount columnCount cellValues '
    classInstanceVariableNames: ''
    imports: ''
    category: ''
```

Added the following class method:

```
withRowCount: rowCount withColumnCount: columnCount withCellValues: cellValues
    ^self new rowCount: rowCount columnCount: columnCount cellValues: cellValues.
```

Added the following accessor methods:

```
cellValues
    ^cellValues
cellValues: anObject
    cellValues := anObject
columnCount
    ^columnCount
columnCount: anObject
    columnCount := anObject
rowCount
    ^rowCount
rowCount: anObject
    rowCount := anObject
```

I have this code in workspace:

```
|myMatrix|
myMatrix := Matrix rowCount: 5 columnCount: 5 cellValues: 5.
Transcript show: (myMatrix rowCount).
```

But compiler says that message undefined. 
I guess my class method is not working as expected.
Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:  `Matrix` doesn't have a `rowCount:columnCount:cellValues:` method.  You probably meant `Matrix withRowCount: 5 withColumnCount: 5 withCellValues: 5`.

Second, I'm thinking methods return the value of the last expression.  So chaining methods doesn't work quite like that.  (And even if it did, that still looks like one message.)

Your class method should probably read like

```
withRowCount: rowCount withColumnCount: columnCount withCellValues: cellValues
    | newMatrix |
    newMatrix := self new.
    newMatrix rowCount: rowCount;
              columnCount: columnCount;
              cellValues: cellValues.
    ^newMatrix
```

The `;` breaks up the messages and tells Smalltalk to send all three to `newMatrix`.

Then you can use it like

```
|myMatrix|
myMatrix := Matrix withRowCount: 5 withColumnCount: 5 withCellValues: 5.
Transcript show: (myMatrix rowCount).
```

Comment: That was an awesome dumb question from me!
My code was all good except that in the class method, I did not add ';' between parameters! Lol! wasted 6 hours on this.
 withRowCount: rowCount withColumnCount: columnCount withCellValues: cellValues
     ^self new rowCount: rowCount; columnCount: columnCount; cellValues: cellValues.